# Google Chrome shows up on all OS X Lion Spaces when it shouldn't

Tags: google-chrome, osx-lion, osx-spaces, expose

I use spaces to separate work modes. Lately, when I switch to a different space, Chrome shows up there too when it should just stay at its respective space. When I launch mission control, I am unable to drag and drop Chrome window on the space I want. Chrome simply pops up at every space, which is very very annoying, it's breaking my mode separations.

Any solutions or suggestions?

I am on Macbook Pro with OS X Lion v10.7.2 and Chrome v15.0.874.121

Comment: Have you checked Spaces preferences whether Chrome is visible on every space?

Comment: In Lion, there is only the Mission Control preferences, which has very limited options (nothing app specific). Other than that, I am not aware of Spaces preferences, where are they?

Comment: Not on a Mac right now, but have you checked Chrome's Dock icon context menu?

Comment: You were right, thanks Daniel! In the context menu, you can assign it to a specific desktop vs all. That resolved it, thanks! Do you want to write that as an answer, so I can mark this closed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign a space in the Dock item's context menu. Make sure you haven't selected to have Chrome appear on all spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you are struggling with this, the answer suggested for the "Chrome's Dock icon context menu" what worked for me was going in the Chrome tab> right click> Options > Assign to > None

[image]